# How to hide my raspberry pi through vpn (or other way)?

Tags: vpn, raspberry-pi

I want all internet traffic on my raspberry pi to be completely anonymous, but I can't simply install a VPN service or something similar on it to do so. Or can I? Is it possible to hide all internet traffic coming from and going to my raspberry pi (without using the pi itself as a dedicated VPN server)?

I want to hide all traffic from the internet in general (sorry not quite the expert here) so no one can see what I'm doing.

Would [this](http://www.kodipiguide.com/koditutorials/raspberry-pi-vpn-setup/) work?

Comment: When you say "hide" do you mean from your local LAN, your ISP or from the internet in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't simply install a VPN service or something similar on it to do so

[**Why of course you can!**](https://youtu.be/eVpQ5mtFVB4?t=22s) Quick Googling brought me to **[this tutorial](http://vpnonline.pl/en/konfiguracja/raspberry-pi-openvpn)** and [**this tutorial**](http://www.ibvpn.com/billing/knowledgebase/133/OpenVPN-configuration-for-Raspberry-PI.html) in which they explain how to setup an **OpenVPN** client on a Raspberry Pi. Note those tutorials are specifically for those VPN providers, but it can't be hard at all to simply replace the configuration settings for another VPN provider.

Here's a summary of the second tutorial:

> STEP 1. Get your current package list updated:
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> STEP 2. Install the openvpn daemon/package
>
> `sudo apt-get install openvpn`
>
> STEP 3. Download the needed config files and then copy them to the pi (via scp or FTP), then unzip them into `/etc/openvpn`
>
> `sudo mv openvpn.zip /etc/`
>
> sudo unzip openvpn.zip
>
> `cd /etc/openvpn`
>
> STEP 4. (Optional) Edit the config for adding your username and password (won't be prompted to input for each connection attempt). Open a config file that you want to use: after the 'auth-user-pass' add user.txt Save the config, and exit to the shell.
>
> Create the user.txt file with your username and password in it on two different rows, e.g.: `root@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn# cat user.txt username password root@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn#`
>
> Protect the file: `chmod go-rwx user.txt`
>
> Make the conf.sh executable: `chmod +x /etc/openvpn/change_resolv_conf.sh`
>
> STEP 5. Use the following command to get connected (replace config name with the one you want):
>
> `sudo openvpn --daemon --cd /etc/openvpn --config ibVPN-UK-Gosport.ovpn`
>
> Check status:
>
> `curl ifconfig.me`
>
> STEP 6. To disconnect run:
>
> `killall -9 openvpn`